# Regex with no repeated characters

Tags: regex

I'm trying to produce a regex that can match every non repeating a, b or c characters (in one and single match)

I did this: ((a|b|c)(?!\2))+

Here is the regex101 example:
https://regex101.com/r/yJwHOQ/1

It works fine for:

- a or b or c (single character)
- bcabca

Now, I want to improve it so it can also match the first repeated character. For example, when I try bcaa, I want to match bca instead of only bc (in a single match).

Is there a way to improve my regex so it can match this case also?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Ps: it's for PCRE but it would be nice to work also with Python

Comment: Is this correct understood? When there are duplicates, you want to match the first instance but not the second.

Comment: Hi, Paul! Yes if there are duplicates I want to match also the first character. So, a matches, abc matches, bca matches bcaa and bca also matches also bcaaaaaa

Comment: Seems like there is a bug in your logic. Your regex means "Find me a letter (a, b, or c) that's not followed by exact same letter" and that's why regex returns you only 'bc' out of 'bcaa' (since 'a' is followed by another 'a').

Comment: Hi Jaood_xD! Yes, I know it was designed this way originally. However I now want to add the possibility to catch also the first character (and only this one) if there is a duplicate. Nb : I edited my question to make it more clear

Comment: So `bcaa` has two matches `bca` and `a` or do you want to match from start to end or use word boundaries (extract)?  Or what about `bcabc`? This is for PCRE (php)?

Comment: Does [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/dwT0pU/1) match your idea?

Comment: Hi bobble bubble! I want that bcaa only match bca (one and only match). Same as bcaaaaaa will only match bca. bcabc will match bcabc. Yes, it's for PCRE but it would be nice to work with Python also if possible.

Comment: Try this: `(\w)(?!.*?\1)` with the 'global' flag.

Comment: @bobble bubble: close but abb match should be ab

Comment: @PoulBak : close also but it works with letters other than a, b and c and with the global flag I get multiple matches (I want only one match).

Comment: @Stef500 So you just want to get the match from words starting with different [abc] [like this?](https://regex101.com/r/mz1HJ3/1) (I only dropped the right word-boundary from the other demo). `abcba` is a desired match? ([abc] reoccuring but not adjacent)

Comment: @bobblebubble: that's great (and yes abcba is a desired match) !! Can you please explain me the logic of it?

Comment: @Stef500 Do you match these inside text or full strings? (I can put an answer with explanation) If it's inside text I'd use `\b` word boundary for word start, else `^` for string start like [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/slge3i/1). A bit busy right now, give me couple of minutes :)

Comment: It's full strings. I want to check if a string answer the specifcation (not repeated characters from a, b or c and if repeated catch only the first character). Ps : take all the time you need. I know I was close but I lack experience

Comment: Yes, you were close and I think its a good question. Also good to explain the context, what input can look like and the expected output. If it's needed for extraction or matching... :)

Comment: @Stef500 Just to mention in .NET you could use [`^(?:([abc])(?<!\1.))+`](http://www.regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3a%28%5babc%5d%29%28%3f%3c!%5c1.%29%29%2b&i=a%0d%0aabb%0d%0aabcba%0d%0acbad%0d%0acba%0d%0abcabc&o=m) but in most regex flavors afaik backreference `\1` is not allowed in a lookbehind. With a little trick it's [still possible](https://regex101.com/r/TeNMcd/1) (put it into a lookahead inside) however I don't think this is easier to get along with, just for playing - somehow I have a feeling there are simpler solutions... also than the one of my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is a *zero-length* assertion. It matches at a position, eg between `b` and `c`.

For example in the string "[abb](https://regex101.com/r/btZ9Wv/1)" after first `b` there is aonther `b`. The *negative* lookahead disallows that and just `a` gets matched. To match what *fails ahead* `[abc]` can be reused without condition.

```
^(?:([abc])(?!\1))*[abc]
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/TyEMnj/1)

*Note*: In PCRE a [group reference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html) can be used to match the same again, eg [`(?1)` for `([abc])`](https://regex101.com/r/afPPwg/1).
In .NET regex *capture reference* inside a lookbehind would work: [`^(?:([abc])(?<!\1.))+`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3a%28%5babc%5d%29%28%3f%3c!%5c1.%29%29%2b&i=a%0d%0aabb%0d%0aabcba%0d%0acbad%0d%0acba%0d%0abcabc&o=m)